# disable autosort of dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm creating dataframe

```
ohlc = pd.DataFrame( { 'date':[date2num(dup.parse(x)) for x in rates['date']],
                       'open':rates['open'],
                       'high':rates['high'],
                       'low':rates['low'],
                       'close':rates['close'] }  )
```

and i expect following order of columns (date, open, high, low, close).
But something triggered and i get such an order (close, date, high, low, open).

please advise me, how can turn off sorting or way to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making your dataframe from a dict, which does not have a defined order of its keys by its nature.  You could instead use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), or simply re-order your dataframe after its construction:

```
ohlc_ordered = ohlc[['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']]
```